# MomentJS/Date object UTC by default

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datetime, momentjs

I am using MomentJS in my angular project and i'm having a lot of issues with different date timezones.

My app should not take into consideration any timezones, however this chaos between my backend api and frontend, when i send standard moment objects to c# backend it converts it to UTC by default and i always get the dates -1 day.

Can i set MomentJS or javascript Date object to always default to UTC AND ignore hour/minutes/seconds ?

When i do: `moment()`  it gets populated with today value based on timezone and based on current hour.

I want to make `moment()` always have UTC value and time always be 00:00:00 in my entire app.

Is it also possible to achieve this also with `new Date()` ?

Right now i've been always using `.toUTCString()` after `new Date()` but i have a ton of date variables in my solution and it's not really ok to make sure everything has `.toUTCString()` after it all the time, if another dev misses this it will cause issue. I'm trying to find a way to standardize this at project level.

My major issue is with momentJS compare methods `.isBefore()`, `.isSame()`, `.isAfter()`. Because all my dates contain different hours and different time zone when the compare happens it will take them into account and not behave how i want them to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) with `moment`.

And then set default `UTC` timezone with code below:

```
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';
...
moment.tz.setDefault('Etc/UTC');
```

A possible option in Angular could be to create a singleton instance `LocaleService` to manage localization related parameters.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LocaleService {

  constructor() {
    this.setDefaultTimezone();
  }

  setDefaultTimezone() {
    moment.tz.setDefault('Etc/UTC');
  }

  // other stuff related to localization
  ...setCurrentTimezone()
  ...setLocale()
}
```

And then, we need to provide this service via `AppModule`, and also don't forget to inject it in a global component, for instance `AppComponent`, in order to be instantiated.

Comment: Would this work on a global level ? i tried calling this in app.component.ts but then when i uses a moment object in another component it still defaulted to my timezone instead of UTC.

Comment: It won't change an existing moment instance, but if you created a new one it's fine. [https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/default-timezone/](moment-timezone doc)

Comment: Answer updated. The best is to put this code into a singleton instance `LocaleService` which is in charge to set default locale to UTC, and other stuff related to localization. This global service is imported into `AppModule`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use moment in *UTC mode* in this way:

`let m = moment().utc()`

then, to reset the time to midnight of that day you can call this method:

`m.startOf('day')`

you can also chain it all together:

`let m = moment.utc().startOf('day')`

and if you print it it will be something like:

```
console.log(m.format())
// 2019-07-02T00:00:00Z
```

You can also do it with the native *Date*, but you'll have to write a bunch of code that momentjs already has...

I hope this answer your questions!

for reference have a look here:
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

and here:
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/

Comment: Thanks, this also helps a lot! But i will go with the above answer as it helps me define a default TZ at project level.